# Powershell Unload Module... completely

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm working on debugging a Powershell project.  I'm using `Import-Module` to load the PS module from my C# dll and everything works fine.  Calling `Remove-Module` does not fully unload the module though as the DLL is still locked and can not be deleted.

Is there a way to get PSH to fully unload the module and release the DLL so that I can copy over it and reload it again using `Import-Module` without restarting the PSH console?

**Update**
So if you load a module into a seperate AppDomain does it still work like a normal module?  Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: I've been exploring this as well -- I want to distribute a nuget package as a powershell plugin, and in order to allow the package to be updated, it needs to be able to delete the old package version (which contains the supporting dlls).  I think wrapping the functions in an command line exe is probably going to be the best bet. :(

Answer (score 36):

There is a workaround. Open up another instance of PowerShell:

```
PS > powershell
PS > [load DLL]
PS > [do work]
PS > exit
```

After the exit, you'll be brought back to the instance of PowerShell from which you made this call (assuming you made the `powershell` call inside and instance of PowerShell). You can pass in any of the normal arguments to `powershell`, so you can use -Command or -File. E.g.,

```
PS > powershell -Command '[load DLL]; [do work]' # Executes a command and exits
PS > powershell -Command '.\myscript.ps1 param1 param2' # Executes the script and exits
PS > powershell -File .\myscript.ps1 param1 param2 # Executes a script and exits.
```

When PowerShell exits, it will release the lock on the DLL, allowing you to continue working.

All of this was done from the PowerShell command line interface. I haven't tested what happens if you throw `powershell` in the middle of a script or if this works within ISE. (I suspect it works within ISE.) Even if if doesn't work inside a script, this is still useful during development.

Edit:

Did some checking. So this seems to work fine from within scripts and in ISE, but there's a caveat within ISE. From ISE, you can't read any input from the user while you're inside the separate PowerShell process. If you try, the script or commands stop to wait, but no input box is shown like normal, and of course, you can't type directly into the output window in ISE. So if you need to prompt for input in the middle of `[do work]`, prompt **before** firing up a new instance of PowerShell, and pass it into the work as a parameter. These aren't problems at all if you're using the regular PowerShell command line.

Comment: A few years late to the party, but a similar workaround is to do the work in a [background job](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847783.aspx).  Powershell background jobs are run as separate processes.  You still can't read user input, but it's a bit more flexible than spawning a new instance of Powershell.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Background jobs look like they're designed for async operations. If that's what you need anyway, that sounds like a great option, but if you don't, that feels a lot of added complexity when you could just run the process in line. Are there other benefits I'm not seeing?

Comment: Two benefits I can think of: First, you pass a script block to a job, which allows you to keep your script in one source file.  And second, you can pass (serializable) objects as parameters to job, instead of just text parameters.  It's a similar workaround to yours, which is why I didn't post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 18):

No. As PowerShell uses .NET underneath it has the same requirements.
You cannot unload a dll from a .NET AppDomain without unloading the AppDomain itself. As the PowerShell UI lives in the same AppDomain this is not possible.

Answer (score 12):

I see a few workable answers here, but here's mine, in case this is still a problem for someone (and this is pretty lazy, which is nice).

```
Enter-PSSession -localcomputername
[load dlls]
[execute script(s)]
Exit-PSSession
```

Long story short, creating a PSSession for your local computer creates a different powershell session, including what's considered "loaded", and when you exit, it cleans things up for you.

Comment: FYI this does not appear to work in PowerShell Core (tested 7.0.3 on Windows 10) unless you configure winrm first. This can be done using the command "winrm quickconfig" or "Enable-PSRemoting -Force" (force skips the confirmation)

Answer (score 8):

In the context of Cmdlet development, and having issues with unloading your DLL, there are two approaches that I use.

Firstly, I develop in Visual Studio, and setup an external program (PowerShell) to load my Cmdlet.  This way, my module loads when I start debugging, and unloads when I stop debugging.

Second, on those occasions where I know I want to load a module, do some work, and ensure the module is unloaded afterwards, I use a second instance of PowerShell.  This has been discussed in other answers, and my answer below shows how I enable this workflow by using a function with an alias in my Profile. I change the prompt so I can have a visual reminder that I am in a "recursive PowerShell window".

**Create a script in your profile to start PowerShell**

```
function Start-DebugPowerShell
{
    PowerShell -NoProfile -NoExit -Command {
        function prompt {
            $newPrompt = "$pwd.Path [DEBUG]"
            Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow $newPrompt
            return '> '
        }
    }
}
Set-Alias -Name sdp -Value Start-DebugPowerShell
```

**Edit debug settings for your Cmdlet project**

*Start external program*:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

*Command line arguments*:

`-NoProfile -NoExit -Command "Import-Module .\MyCoolCmdlet.dll"`

**Debug your Module**

Now from Visual Studio, start debugger with <kbd>F5</kbd>, and you have a new PowerShell window with your Cmdlet loaded, and you can debug it however you like.

**Use the 'sdp' alias from any PowerShell window**

Since the Start-DebugPowerShell function is in our profile and we gave it an alias `sdp`, you can use this to start a second instance of PowerShell anytime you need it.

Comment: I can confirm that the Visual Studio debugging portion of this answer is a very good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this holds true for PowerShell: in the .NET world the only way to unload an assembly is to load it into a different `AppDomain`; once an assembly is loaded to an `AppDomain` it remains loaded for the lifetime of that `AppDomain`.

---

Here's an example from a thread asking pretty much the same question and showing a couple ways to create and load the module into a new AppDomain:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=30789124&threadid=30766269

Comment: I expected this may be the case, however I don't think you can load an interact with PSH modules this way.  So the real answer is likely that what I'm trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: It's possible to load & unload DLLs and replace the DLL using the AppDomain shadow copy feature. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633140/MEF-and-AppDomain-Remove-Assemblies-On-The-Fly

Comment: The link in the answer is dead.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issues and ended up wrapping the DLL I wanted to load inside a commandline exe which I then called from the script.  In that way I avoided loading the DLL inside my application at all.

Comment: sadly, I think that is what I may end up doing as well

Answer (score 3):

I use a simple script that renames target DLL and loads it as module. Here we have 2 hacks:

1. when module is loading from .net assembly object we got loaded module with name "dynamic_code_module_FirstPowershellModule"
2. so before import we unload this module and create new one from renamed file

previous assemblies stay unused in domain

script must be run after each project rebuild

```
Get-Module -Name "*FirstPowershellModule*" | Remove-Module
$ii++
$destPath = "D:\Dev\FirstPowershellModule\FirstPowershellModule\bin\Debug\FirstPowershellModule" + $ii+ ".dll"
Copy-Item D:\Dev\FirstPowershellModule\FirstPowershellModule\bin\Debug\FirstPowershellModule.dll -Destination $destPath
$ass = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($destPath)
import-module -Assembly $ass
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the DLL and load that copy.
You can Reload DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

The PS modules are .net assemblies, when you `Import-Module`, you load them into the AppDomain of the PowerShell Host(the application). `Remove-Module` just removes modules from the current session.

According to msdn,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101(v=vs.80).aspx

> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all of the application domains that contain it. Use the Unload method from AppDomain to unload the application domains. For more information, see Unloading an Application Domain.

You could start a new PowerShell host in a new AppDomain, import your module to the host and do the PowerShell job. The module is as normal as it was running in your previous host. The only difference is that it is in a host running in a different AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

I had some external module (*ImportExcel*) I wanted to update like this and it [did not work](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/11). For this situation **`Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser <MyExternalModuleName>`** (in case it is in your users module folder, otherwise omit the `-Scope ...` param) worked.

(How they managed it internally - I don't know, but you keep your current PS session.)