# How to get Powershell-ISE to release Cmdlet DLL

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm development a Cmdlet and using Powershell-ISE to test.  ISE is keeping my DLL locked and preventing from rebuilding and then reloading.

I've tried call remove ps-snappin, but the DLL remains locked.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible to unload DLLs completely. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337961/powershell-unload-module-completely

Comment: @Roman Thank you.  I missed that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roman points out, this can't be done AFAICT.  It isn't a PowerShell ISE issue as much as it is a .NET issue with assembly loading i.e. .NET doesn't support assembly unloading.  It would be nice if there was a way to add the snapin via a secondary AppDomain and then unload that whole AppDomain.  I'm not aware of any such attempt to do this in a host.

Answer (score 0):

Keith and Roman are correct. Once you've loaded a .NET assembly into an AppDomain, the only way to release it is to close the AppDomain.