# PowerShell: how does the PowerShell instantiate C# classes

Tags: c#, powershell

Initially, I think PowerShell instantiate one class only when the cmdlet tagged on this class is called. On execution, each cmdlet falls into the BeginProcess -> ProcessRecord -> EndProcess(StopProcess) path, and after the EndProcess is done, it seems the process will end and then the memory will collect all these class objects as garbage.Therefore each class should live in their own life cycle and not share any resources. When we are calling these cmdlets,

However I find that classes do share the same static values in the same module. For example, assume in my project I have two classes:

```
namespace PSDSL
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "MyTest")]
    public class GetMyTest : Cmdlet
    {
        public static GlobalUserName = "";
        [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
        public string Filepath { get; set; }
        protected override void InnerProcessRecord()
        {
            if (_filepath != null)
            {
                GlobalUserName = _filepath;
            }
             Console.WriteLine(GlobalUserName);
        }
    }
}

namespace PSDSL
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "MyTest2")]
    public class GetMyTest2 : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
        public string Filepath { get; set; }
        protected override void InnerProcessRecord()
        {
            if (_filepath != null)
            {
                GlobalUserName = _filepath;
            }
             Console.WriteLine(GlobalUserName);
        }
    }
}
```

The two commands are pretty similar except one defines a static GlobalUserName. Calling these 2 cmdlets shows that the GlobalUserName can be read\write from both cmdlets.

My confusion is that,  when are the classes be instaniated?

Comment: Static fields are indeed stay in memory and if public visible by all instances of classes. If your expectation is that for *each* class its assembly loaded into separate AppDomain (the only way static to have unique values) than it is not the case for PowerShell (or any other sane code that instantiates .Net objects)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So are the whole custom module get instantiated when it is loaded in PowerShell?

Comment: What you are describing is not specific to Powershell. This is how .net in general designed. Static field are shared across entire AppDomain and each assembly stay loaded / active for the entire life time of the AppDomain. Thus static fields has very little to do with garbage collection, they are considered roots and are not collected - which, if you think about it is pretty logical

Comment: @zespri You are right. I wasn't sure when the life cycle of the AppDomain ends - is it by the end of the command itself (if the module classes are instantiated on invocation) or by the end of the powerhsell, which is the right case. This helps to understand designing the PowerShell modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole assembly loaded at once and stays loaded till restart of the PowerShell prompt.

**Details:**

Smallest unit of code isolation in .Net is Assembly (in most cases single managed DLL).

Process that uses managed runtime can't load less than single assembly at a time - so all classes from that assembly (and related once on demand) will be loaded together. As result all static fields will be present at the same time in memory (note that static fields are initialized "before first use of the class" which mean they are not necessary initialized on load of the assembly).

There also no way to "unload" class or even assembly without using separate AppDomains. PowerShell does not use multiple AppDomains to load assemblies for different modules (generally cross-AddDomain calls require special attention during implementation and you'd know about it by now). As result once loaded module stays in memory till you quit PowerShell (covered in [Powershell Unload Module... completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337961/powershell-unload-module-completely)).

Since assembly is loaded once for all commandlets in it all static fields will be present at once and keep they values till exiting of PowerShell.

Side note: I'd strongly recommend avoiding `static` fields for anything but really static immutable data in general. It is way to easy to leave some random values there and impact future code. In PowerShell pipeline is the way to pass information between commandlets, other types of processes (WinForms, ASP.Net,...) have they own preferred mechanism to pass data instead of using static.

Comment: You are right that we want to avoid unnecessary static. The static value here is only for demo, I will need the static values to store values from app.config, which I can use PowerShell's SessionState as well. In this case, do you know how SessionState and static value behave differently?

Comment: @jamesdeath123 ASP.Net `SessionState` is not true static - it is just static property that internally does  "global session State Storage -> GetStateByUserId(Request.Cookies[SessionIs])". There are other similar "static" properties like `CurrentThread`, `CurrentRequest` that actually give you value based on current execution context.