# Wonkiness with dot sourcing and powershell clases

Tags: powershell

This one has me thoroughly confused. In some scenarios, running a script that dot-sources another script that defines a class does not reflect changes to the class. Here's the repro.

Script common.ps1:

```
class A
{
    A()
    {
        Write-Host 'hi'
    }
}
```

Script myscript.ps1:

```
. .\common.ps1
[A]::new() | out-null
```

In a powershell terminal, I then run

```
. .\common.ps1
[A]::new() | out-null
.\myscript.ps1
```

outputs

```
hi
hi
```

I then change common.ps1 by replacing 'hi' with 'bye', and again run

```
. .\common.ps1
[A]::new() | out-null
.\myscript.ps1
```

To get this output (my comments added):

```
bye # expected
hi # what?!?!
```

The fact that the change is not-reflected when myscript.ps1 does the dot sourcing but is when the dot sourcing is done locally blows my mind. If I don't dot-source locally, running myscript.ps1 always reflects any changes to common.ps1. And it is only when my change is to some part of the class that it does not have an effect (I can add a Write-Host outside of the class and it will show up).

What's going on? Somehow myscript.ps1 can't load the updated class even though the local shell can? I imagine this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804102/) but the inconsistency between local shell and myscript.ps1 has me scratching my head.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337961/powershell-unload-module-completely and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394358/powershell-how-does-the-powershell-instantiate-c-sharp-classes

Comment: Just saw other wonkiness that didn't involve a class, where the dot-sourcing seemed to be one-behind the changes. So perhaps this isn't even class specific, but classes are just a way to expose it.

Comment: PowerShell try to resolve type tokens at parse time. If it succeed, then it record result in parsed syntax tree, rather then resolve type token in runtime each time. Also PowerShell cache parsed script files. If it see that file does not changed from last time, then it reuse already parsed syntax tree, rather than reparse file again and re-resolving type tokens in new context.

Comment: @PetSerAI - That doesn't explain why the changes to the class have an effect in the top-level shell but not in the called script, does it? Both places dot source the file after the change, but only one gets the changes.

Comment: *Also PowerShell cache parsed script files.* Add/remove some meaningless space in script and try again.

Comment: This has no effect.

Comment: @aggieNick02 It [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUmN5.png) for me.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Wow, you are right, my apologies. I had added and deleted a space, then saved, which updated the modtime on the file but did not fix the issue. But if I actually change the file (only add or remove a space, not both) so that the file is different, the issue goes away. This means the caching is done not off the modtime of the file, but off of some hash of it.

Comment: @PetSerAl If you want to post the comment about the caching as an answer, I'm happy to accept it. Thanks for going to such trouble to try my code out and figure out the issue.