# Debug Powershell cmdlet (written in c#) in VS Code

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, powershell-cmdlet

Another question addresses how to debug a Powershell cmdlet written in C# in Visual Studio 2015-19: 
[Debugging / unloading PowerShell Cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917730/debugging-unloading-powershell-cmdlet)

I could somehow invoke a script like this:

```bsh
function Start-DebugPowerShell
{
    PowerShell -NoProfile -NoExit -Command {
        function prompt {
            $newPrompt = "$pwd.Path [DEBUG]"
            Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow $newPrompt
            return '> '
        }
    }
}
Set-Alias -Name sdp -Value Start-DebugPowerShell
```

This makes it easy to create a temp PS instance that you can `exit` to unload.

Or I can set the Debug options in the  VS Project like this and it works great:
[image]

I'd like to do the same thing, but using Visual Studio Code. I know how to debug this using attach (e.g. with these `launch.json` settings:

```
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "justMyCode": false
    }
```

I can't figure out how to craft a `launch.json` that first launches `pwsh`. The project type is `csharp` and thus the only `type`s available in `launch.json` are `coreclr` and `clr`.

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer, but what you are looking for is the configuration that should be used to debug a PS module written in C#. This can be done via following configuration added to `lanuch.json`:

```
 {
     "name": "PowerShell cmdlets: pwsh",
     "type": "coreclr",
     "request": "launch",
     "preLaunchTask": "build",
     "program": "pwsh",
     "args": [
         "-NoExit",
         "-NoProfile",
         "-Command",
         "Import-Module ${workspaceFolder}/myModule/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/myModule.dll",
     ],
     "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
     "stopAtEntry": false,
     "console": "integratedTerminal"
 }
```

Notice the line `Import-Module` as this has to point to the dll which is the PS Module. Then when you run this configuration in VSC and setup some breakpoints in C#, you can invoke your cmdlet in the builtin Terminal and it will start the debugging session.

MS has a very good documentation on that: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/using-vscode-for-debugging-compiled-cmdlets?view=powershell-7.3#configuring-launchjson-for-powershell)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).