# Powershell opc xml write UInt32 array

Tags: powershell, wsdl, opc

I've managed to read an OPC XML item with a Powershell script

```
$wsdl=(Join-path $PSScriptRoot "OpcXmlDa1.00.wsdl")

$global:Proxy = New-WebserviceProxy $wsdl –Namespace X
$global:Options = New-Object X.RequestOptions
$Options.ReturnItemName = $true;
$Options.ReturnItemTime = $true;

$global:ItemList = New-Object X.ReadRequestItemList
$global:RItemList = New-Object X.ReplyItemList
$global:Errors = New-Object X.OPCError
$global:Item = New-Object X.ReadRequestItem 

# Read from OPC server
$Proxy.Url = "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx"
$Item.ItemName = "xxx/xxx/xxx"
$ItemList.Items = $Item
$Proxy.Read($Options, $ItemList, [ref]$RItemList, [ref]$Errors)

#Show result
$rTimeStamp = $RItemList.Items[0].Timestamp.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
$rItemName = $RItemList.Items[0].ItemName 
$rValue = $RItemList.Items[0].Value 
Write-Host ("{0}: {1}={2}" -f $rTimeStamp, $rItemName, $rValue)
```

In my result above I see the following in `$RItemList.Items[0]`

```
DiagnosticInfo:$null
Value: [UInt32[32]]
Quality: [OPCQuality]
ValueTypeQualifier: $null
ItemPath: ""
ItemName: "xxx/xxx/xxx"
ClientItemHandle: $null
Timestamp: 2020-12 19 01:00:00
TimestampSpecified: $true
ResultID: $null
```

and when I dive deeper into Value above I see that it is read as expected. So far so good...

Now to my problem; I cannot understand how to write to this same Item via another script.

This is my attempt

```
$wsdl=(Join-path $PSScriptRoot "OpcXmlDa1.00.wsdl")

$Global:Proxy = New-WebserviceProxy $wsdl –Namespace X
$Global:Options = New-Object X.RequestOptions
$Options.ReturnItemName = $true;
$Options.ReturnItemTime = $true;
$Options.ReturnDiagnosticInfo = $true;

$Global:writeItemList = New-Object X.WriteRequestItemList
$Global:RItemList = New-Object X.ReplyItemList
$Global:Errors = New-Object X.OPCError
    
$Global:ItemSessionRequest = New-Object X.ItemValue
$ItemSessionRequest.ValueTypeQualifier = 'xsd:unsignedInt' #<- I believe that this might be the issue?
$ItemSessionRequest.ItemPath = ""
$ItemSessionRequest.ItemName = "xxx/xxx/xxx"
$ItemSessionRequest.Value = @($x;$y;$z) #<- I have what I want to write in $x, $y, $z

# Write to OPC server
$Proxy.Url = "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx"
$ReturnValuesOnReply = $true
$writeItemList.Items = $ItemSessionRequest
$Proxy.Write($Options, $writeItemList, $ReturnValuesOnReply, [ref]$RItemList, [ref]$Errors)
```

I get two errors (I'm running via VSC-code).

Error #1:

```
DiagnosticInfo     : This value to write cannot be NULL
Value              :
Quality            :
ValueTypeQualifier :
ItemPath           :
ItemName           : xxx/xxx/SessionRequest
ClientItemHandle   :
Timestamp          : 1970-01-01 00:59:59
TimestampSpecified : True
ResultID           : http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/:E_BADTYPE
```

I've assumed that this has to do with my choice of `$ItemSessionRequest.ValueTypeQualifier` (where I've tried a lot of alternatives).

Error #2: This error comes if I run the script a second time in the same instance

```
Cannot convert argument "Options", with value: "X.RequestOptions", for "Write" to type "X.RequestOptions": "Cannot convert the "X.RequestOptions" value of type "X.RequestOptions" to type "X.Request
Options"."
At C:\bla.bla.ps1:79 char:1
+ $Proxy.Write($Options, $writeItemList, $ReturnValuesOnReply, [ref]$RI ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

I guess this has something to do with the $Proxy variable

I'm grateful for help and I apologize if I missed something relevant, but I have done my best...

Comment: I believe it should be `xs:unsignedInt`. I have no idea about the 2nd error. Maybe it comes from your inconsistent use of `global:` for some variables, which is quite unusual and could lead to problems. Normally you should just write e. g. `$Proxy = ...`.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the tips. But `xs:unsignedInt` gave the same error. And regarding `global:`-scope, I agree that I'm inconsistsent. But I've tried in many ways to alter the scope of the variables and remove all variables in the end of the script to have the script behave the same during the second run of the script in the same instance. But I still get the 2nd error.

Comment: How are you calling the script? If you dot-source it like `. script.ps1` then all variables will be kept in memory even after script finishes. If you call it like `& script.ps1` then normal variables will automatically be removed from memory when the script ends and garbage collector kicks in. So the next time the script runs, it will start from a clear state. The exception are `global:` variables, which stay in memory anyway, so you shouldn't use them.

Comment: You can also try to call `dispose()` on the objects you created with `New-Object`, at the end of the script. I'm not sure it's necessary here, but it doesn't hurt. E. g. `$Global:Proxy.dispose()`. This should be done in a `finally` block to make sure it runs even when a script-terminating error happens.

Comment: Thank you once again @zett42 . I've started the script by `. script.ps1`, `& script.ps1`  and by running it in debug mode i Visual Studio Code. All methods gives the same 2nd error. I've also tried your tip to call `dispose()` at the end of the script without getting rid of the error (I've also tried `Get-Variable -Exclude PWD,*Preference | Remove-Variable -EA 0`)...

Comment: I now strongly believe that error 2 comes from that my wsdl module doesn't unload between consecutive runs, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337961/powershell-unload-module-completely)

Answer (score 0):

In this case problem no 1 was solved by the following

`$ItemSessionRequest.Value = @($x;$y;$z)`

A work around for problem no 2 was by using a new session inside the script, see [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6)